# Can't load custom font in Create React App project

Tags: fonts, sass, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app project, using absolute imports and css modules (scss). I am trying to define a custom font-face but the import is not being resolved.

Tried everything suggested in the documentation.

my folder structure

```
jsconfig.json
public
src
L assets
 L fonts
  L impact.ttf
L index.js
L index.scss
```

in my index.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'impact';
  src: url(./assets/fonts/impact.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

my jsconfig.json (for absolute importing)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

my index.js imports `import './index.scss'` at the top of the file.
when i try to compile this code, my component throws an error saying the font file cannot be resolved...

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/brush.ttf' in '/Users/xxx/project/src/containers/mycomponent'
```

Also using `node-sass` so the scss files work.
Cant figure this one out...

Answer (score 5):

In `create-react-app` the default folder for assets (Images, Fonts, and Files...) is the `public` folder.

So instead of creating a `./src/assets` folder, just move your 'fonts' folder inside the '/public' (`./public/fonts`)

For more info, check: 
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: It looks like they are recommending the opposite now: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,

For scss in react, put the font files in the same folder as your component and point to them with relative path. Or you can put them anywhere in the src folder and refer to them.

eg

```
src: url(./fonts/impact.ttf)
```

Then webpack will collect those files and automatically pack them to later make them available at `/static/fonts/impact.ttf` on your server, just like your public files.